# conflicting types in priority queue C

Tags: c, priority-queue

structure:

```
typedef int TIPAS;

struct sarasas{
    int prioritetas;
    TIPAS kintamasis;
    struct sarasas *kitas;
};
typedef struct sarasas elementas;

struct priorEile{
    elementas* galva;
    int ilgis;
};
typedef struct priorEile* p_eile;
typedef struct priorEile** p_eile2;
```

header:

```
void sukurti(p_eile2);
```

function

```
void sukurti(p_eile* eilute){
    *eilute=(struct priorEile*)calloc(1,sizeof(struct priorEile));
    (*eilute)->galva=NULL;
}
```

it's all about creating priority queue.
I have an error conflicting typer in "sukurti" and previous declaration of "sukurti" was there. Any solutions? Where I made a mistake?

Comment: Note: They say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Don't `typedef` pointers! It obfuscates your code and results in confusion.

Comment: And compare the two declarations!

Comment: Curious, who or what document suggested using a `typedef` with a pointer like `typedef struct priorEile* p_eile;`?

Answer (score 1):

You have the error because the type of return value of function `sukurti` differs between the declaration and the definition.

Try changing `int sukurti(p_eile* eilute){` to `void sukurti(p_eile* eilute){`.